# Python: How can I defeat a lock in mangled variable which uses a special method?

Tags: python, class, name-mangling

In python, one is able to use [special methods](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames) to achieve something similar to operator overloading in C++ by defining a special method for __setattr__. I have seen some coders use this to create a read-only lock using a mangled variable name. That's pretty clever until I need to an element to an array of the locked class. For example, [FreeIPA implements this](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/18942538/). This would be fairly straightforward to defeat by simply setting exampleArray._ReadOnly__locked = False, except this is ALSO caught by the __setattr__ special method and results in the error

> "ipa: ERROR: AttributeError: locked: cannot set NameSpace._ReadOnly__locked to False"

Is there a simple and clever way to set this back to read-write mode so that I can insert my value into the array?

Comment: Have you considered that there may be a very good reason why the authors of FreeIPA have gone to such lengths to make what you want to do difficult?

Comment: Yep. But there is also a good reason why I want to defeat it. The project also offer a [plugin/extension architecture](https://abbra.fedorapeople.org/freeipa-extensibility.html) and if you wanted to, say, add comments your [DNS](http://www.freeipa.org/page/DNS) entries you very quickly run into the read-only lock.

Comment: The `ReadOnly` docstring actually *shows* you how to bypass its protections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the docstring, you can use the default implementation of `__setattr__` from `object`.

```
class ReadOnly(object):
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        raise AttributeError("This instance is read only.")

r = ReadOnly()
object.__setattr__(r, 'name', 'value')
print r.name # 'value'
```

The potential issue here is when your parent class does something special when setting objects. In this case, your resulting instance may be inconsistent.